# Javascript resize function for iframes does not work in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, resize

I used a javascript resize function i found on stackoverflow and it works great with IE and FF. However in Google Chrome it can only resize iframes that are bigger than the previous one. If it has to resize smaller iframes, it takes the same height and adds 30px.

I assume it has got something to do with retrieving the scrollHeight, but i don't know how to fix it.

I already tried to use a timeout because I read somewhere that might help, but it doesn't.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    function autoResize(id){
        var newheight;
        if(document.getElementById)
        {
            newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            newheight=newheight+30;
        }
        document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    }

    <iframe src="<?php echo "$LC"; ?>/home.html" name="iframe" id="iframe" width="435px" height="10px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="margin-left:-10px;padding-bottom:20px;" onLoad="setTimeout(autoResize('iframe'),250);";">
```

Edit: solved it by changing the function to

```
    function autoResize(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).height = document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+15; //Chrome

        document.getElementById(id).height = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+15; //FF, IE
    }
```

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer - its the recommended way of answering your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function autoResize(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).height = document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+15; //Chrome

    document.getElementById(id).height = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+15; //FF, IE
}
```

Comment: An if/else block can be applied using jQuery.browser